# PUT on a specific MQ Cluster

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I'm using WebSphere MQ. I have 3 QMs: QM1, QM2, and QM3. QM1 and QM2 form together an MQ Cluster named CLS12, while the QM2 and QM3 form CLS23. In other words, QM2 is in two clusters.

I'd like to put a message (actually, it will be IIB to put a message) on QM2, but the target queues will actually be local on QM1 and QM3, but shared in the clusters. However, I would like to be able to choose to which cluster (not QM) the message should be put to.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer?  No.

MQ performs name resolution by queue and queue manager name.  At no time during name resolution is the cluster name available to the application putting the message as a way to resolve the destination.

It is possible to create QMgr aliases with names that match a particular cluster and get behavior similar to what you seek but it isn't reliable.  Clusters are a namespace in which the queues and topics can reside.  When clusters overlap, the namespaces overlap.  So even though it's possible to fake the routing using aliases, changes in the namespace for either the queue, the alias or the queue manager that cause a name collision or cause cross-contamination of the overlapping cluster namespaces will break the name rresolution.